# Chromium splits text over page break during printing

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, chromium

When printing on Chromium/Chrome, the page break cuts text in half:

[image]

The DOM is nothing special.  Everything is wrapped in one div, and then there's a couple more layers of divs and finally a bunch of `<br/>`s and `<b>` like this:

[image]

Are there any workarounds?  Is this is a known bug?